# Is there Delphi support for GIS specialized databases?

Tags: delphi, gis, postgis, spatialite

Such as [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) and [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/)?

I am using AnyDac, which does not provide support. Are there any other components which can make life easier for me when working with such GIS enabled databses in Delphi?

---

[Update] If not an you want one, then please post requierments to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657702/what-features-should-an-interface-component-to-gis-databases-have). Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, but you might look at pgDac. www.devart.com

Comment: I might look at a lot of things. And I *am* googling

Comment: +1: A Delphi SpatiaLite binding sounds like a good opensource project if somebony hasn't started it yet!

Comment: +1 @menjaraz -->  https://sourceforge.net/p/add_project   ;-)

Comment: Ad PostGIS, it's almost impossible (and not useful) to write a generic library for all the supported features. Well, you can wrap functions like e.g. `ST_Distance`, `ST_DWithin` and similar, but most of the time you'll be using those functions in a more complex query and so it's not much useful having function for getting such elementary values. And what about data types like `geometry` or `geography` ? They are binary formats which are not useful to store on the client side. You usually construct them on the server side with WKT, or e.g. from coordinates.